# How do I re-open a window in TideSDK?

Tags: tidesdk

I am trying to add a simple "About" dialog but when I call `open()` more than once it gets mad. Currently I am making a new dialog every time and calling `open()` on it, but I would prefer to make one and `show()` and `hide()` but once the dialog has been closed it doesn't want to be displayed again.

What should I do?

Answer (score 1):

Did you check this link?
http://tidesdk.multipart.net/docs/user-dev/generated/#!/api/Ti.UI.UserWindow

Basically I would think of creating a global variable for the "About" window and initialize it in the loading of the application  using `Ti.UserWindow.createWindow();` then with button click I can use 
`aboutWindow.hide();` and another one `aboutWindow.show();`

Answer (score 0):

```
var CurrentWindow = Ti.UI.getCurrentWindow();
CurrentWindow.addEventListener(Ti.CLOSE, function(event) {

var process = Ti.Process.createProcess([Ti.API.application.getPath() + \\YOUREXECUTABLE.exe']);

process.launch();

});
CurrentWindow.close();
```